# ffmpwg failed with code 1 at ChildProcess

Tags: node.js, firebase, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions, child-process

I am trying to add a watermark over the a video in firebase storage using firebase functions and ffmpeg,
but no matter what I try it always exit the same error.

```
 return spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', tmpFilePath, '-vf',`drawtext="text='hello World'`, tmpFilePath]);
```

And I tried this as well:

```
        return spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', tmpFilePath, '-i', tmpLogoPath, '-filter_complex', '"overlay=10:10"', tmpFilePath]);
```

console log:

```
ChildProcessError: `ffmpeg -i /tmp/anything -vf drawtext="text='Stack Overflow' /tmp/anything` failed with code 1
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:132:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:506:15)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:506:15)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:674:12)
at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:120:14)
```

Comment: There is an unterminated quote in your first command. Run the commands in a terminal an check that they work. Then move them to your node.js code taking attention to detail.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón thanks, but I tired the second command on the terminal it worked fine, but when executing on node it gives the same error, i guess that it gives this error only when adding the 'filter_complex overlay'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, I found that this will work if I passed the "overlay=10:10" through a variable and not directly, this code worked for me.

```
var str = "overlay=10:10"
return spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', tmpFilePath, '-i', tmpLogoPath, '-filter_complex', str, tmpFilePath]);
```

Comment: For future reference you might find this documentation helpful about [terminating background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#terminating_background_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes around overlay and try again like this:

```js
return spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', tmpFilePath, '-i', tmpLogoPath, '-filter_complex', 'overlay=10:10', tmpFilePath]);
```